# Daily Complexity Score

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Im struggeling to make daily 'workloads scores' for our current projects

I would like a value per project activity which reflects the days left multiplied with a given complexity factor.

For instance:
Project A starts 1-may-19 and is due 15-may-19 (15 days)
Its a complexity Medium project (factor 1.0)

However the workload is not linear (but in three blocks), and the total project score (15days multiplied with the complexity factor should be distributed like this
First 25% of the days should be given a full work load factor (1)
Last 25% of the days should be given a full work load factor (1)

Whereas the days in between should be reduced in score by 50%

I have tried to draw the concept in the picture
[image]

Anyone who can help me with a code whiich takes this into account, along with 'todays' date?

Comment: Off topic advice from many years of IT project and product management: You are overengineering it.

Comment: How would you propose i did then? if we have these peaks in activity during the duration?

Comment: this is probably a question better suited to [Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com) or [PM](https://pm.stackexchange.com). I'll be glad to give an in-depth answer there. But as food for thought think about this: What do you actually measure with _complexity_? Is it actual complexity (e.g., how many moving parts, unknowns, ...) of a task? Or is value? Or is it time? Or time pressure, even? What do you want to achieve with that? Why do you want to derive a "workload" metric? What does it mean? **What types of decisions shall this metric support**?